# Parse a string of Java float to python int

Tags: java, python, sockets, floating-point, int

I have sockets sending data in string format between java and python. The python client receives floating point numbers in strings as e.g. `data_in = "[F@5cf0ac6e"`, and then attempts to convert them to integers with `value = int(float(data_in[1:]))`. However python returns the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: F@5cf0ac6e`. How can get the java float values to integers in python? Thanks!

Comment: The `@` sign is what's tripping up the conversion. Is the first `F` part of the number, or can `[F@` be safely ignored?

Comment: Sounds like the Java array-to-string conversion is wrong; you should be using `Arrays.toString(float[])`, not `float[].toString()`.  The string you're getting looks meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first three characters of `data_in` are not relevant to the string of hex digits, your slice should be `data_in[3:]`. This will ignore the `[F@` characters, and just convert `5cf0ac6e`.

However, the call to `float()` is not necessary. Instead, use:

```
value = int(data_in[3:], 16)
```

as any floating point information is lost anyway with the conversion to an integer. The `16` parameter to `int()` is necessary because you're converting from base 16 (hexadecimal).